# Best introduction to longitudinal data analysis

Tags: references, panel-data

I have an undergraduate in statistics and I like some mathematical explanation and exposition. I would like to learn the basics of longitudinal analysis for my leisure and edification.

What, if any, is the best mezzanine treatment of this subject?

EDIT: to give gung's clarifications.

Comment: How much math do you want? Do you have an undergraduate degree in statistics, or did you just take statistics classes as an undergrad?

Comment: Hi gung. I have an undergraduate degree in statistics. I like having some 'here is why' math reading similar to the math in Elements of Statistical Learning.

Comment: I love this text: http://gseacademic.harvard.edu/alda/

Answer (score 2):

The book

> Diggle, P., Heagerty, P., Liang, K. Y., & Zeger, S. (2002). Analysis of longitudinal data. Oxford University Press.

is a classic. You can't go wrong starting with that.